# Вывод подразделов каталога через catalog.section.list

Tags: php, битрикс

Пытаюсь сделать одностраничный каталог на Битрикс. С помощью cтруктурs разделов bitrix:catalog.section.list вывожу раздел каталога с товарами. Код шаблона `

```
<? if (!empty($arResult['SECTIONS'])) { ?>
    <?
    $TOP_DEPTH = $arResult["SECTION"]["DEPTH_LEVEL"];
$CURRENT_DEPTH = $TOP_DEPTH;
    $strSectionEdit = CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arParams["IBLOCK_ID"], "SECTION_EDIT");
    $strSectionDelete = CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arParams["IBLOCK_ID"], "SECTION_DELETE");
    $arSectionDeleteParams = array("CONFIRM" => GetMessage('CT_BCSL_ELEMENT_DELETE_CONFIRM')); ?>

    <div class="catalog__tabs">
        <ul class="clear-list">
            
            <? foreach ($arResult['SECTIONS'] as $key => $arSection) {
                $this->AddEditAction($arSection['ID'], $arSection['EDIT_LINK'], $strSectionEdit);
                $this->AddDeleteAction($arSection['ID'], $arSection['DELETE_LINK'], $strSectionDelete, $arSectionDeleteParams);
                
                    
                 ?>
                
                
                
                <li><span id="<? echo $this->GetEditAreaId($arSection['ID']); ?>">
                    <a href="<?= $arSection['SECTION_PAGE_URL'] ?>" data-href="#section_<?= $arSection['ID'] ?>"
                       data-item-id="<?= $arSection['ID'] ?>"
                       class="<?= !$key ? 'active' : '' ?>"><?= $arSection['~NAME'] ?></a>
                </span></li>
                
            <? } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?
    $firstSection = reset($arResult['SECTIONS']);
    $templateData['ACTIVE_SECTION_ID'] = $firstSection['ID'];
}
?>`
```

Вопрос в том, как мне вывести подраздел категории? Вид должен быть типа `<li Razdel><ul Podrazdel></ul></li>`

Answer (score 0):

Вот есть ссылка на решение

[1С-Битрикс Разработчикам](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/support/forum/forum6/topic46272/)

Надо верно устанавливать параметры TOP_DEPTH и в файле шаблона разбирать папки  по глубине.